# What type of light bulb connector is this?

Tags: lighting, bulb

Hi there I have just bought this hanging lamp whose bulb connector type I cannot identify, I got it in Italy and the only thing I am sure is that the light bulb must be some kind of tube shape for it needs to go through a decorative casing that's no longer and no thicker than an index finger. I have included photos:

[image: what the connector looks like]

[image: the decorative casing implying the restriction on the dimensions of the bulb]

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It looks like a [G9 base](http://www.donsbulbs.com/bulbs/g623/socket/db-k540l.jpg) for a [halogen lamp](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B005BYYX44).

Comment: Nice find. That's it.

Answer (score 0):

looks like a older style fluorescent lamp that was used originally in exit fixtures. These were in use before the CFL spiral lamps.

Answer (score -3):

It looks like a Dulux type fluorescent base.

Comment: You could improve this post immensely by providing links as examples, or including photographs of the bulbs you're talking about.